# Get access to specific ADPU functions from cryptoApi or CAPICOM using 3rd party CSP

Tags: smartcard, cryptoapi, capicom, apdu

I have tried for the last 2 months without success and I think it's time I ask here.

I have a **smart card** and got a **CSP from my client**.
I have documents that describe **APDU commands** that I can (and know how to) run.

I need to save small files (data) to the card like name, address, photo etc.
And later on save certificates.

In the documentation I read that you have to do do external authentication to later use secure messaging to access the files on the card.
I have an error somewhere in the mutual authentication algorithm (requires calculating a MAC, DES, TRIPPLE DES etc and i have tried for weeks to get it working...)
I know how to do everything on the card except for functions that require mutual authentication.

**I looked at the functions provided by the CSP and don't see any external authentication** there. The only place i saw non APDU level external auth was in "Windows Smart Card Minidriver Specification" where i see functions like: CardAuthenticateEx.
But i dont know how to call them (which dll they are in).
Should these functions be in the CSP?

**Is it a wrong approach to go low level with APDU commands when i have the CSP.
Should I instead use CryptoAPI or CAPICOM?** If so then **how can i external authenticate and use files if there are no (or i can't find) functions that would write to a file.** (again all these functions are in the "Windows Smart Card Minidriver Specification".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many smartcards follow the Global Platform specification, which (depending on the installed applets on the card and how they are configured) may require a security handshake before communicating with the card.

If you need to write files to the card, you will NOT be using the CSP. The CSP supports OS level cryptographic interactions by re-routing certain crypto calls to the card's processor. To write to a file on the card, you'll be sending APDUs to the card that perform the following functions:

- Authenticate with the card
- (optionally) Select an applet/cardlet
  using the AID (applet ID)
- Select a directory
- Select a file
- Write data to the file

My company makes a plugin for IE and Firefox browsers that helps with this, it includes handshake functions for global platform, and we have a "sandbox" form on our site that lets you test your scripts for card interactions.

Check out https://cardboss.cometway.com for more information.

Comment: Dear @Damien , 
Could you please have a glance at my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32842718/selecting-df-dedicated-file-in-smart-card-return-error-6981 ?