# Selecting DF (Dedicated File) in Smart Card, Return Error 6981

Tags: smartcard, apdu, smartcard-reader, cardreader

I have written a program to communicate with a smart card (Gemalto Company MPCOS applet).
I could successfully connect to card and transmit commands and fetch data.

However I have a problem:
When I used `00 A4 01 00 02 02 00` command to select DF(Dedicated File),
It returned error `69 81` (file indicator is incorrect).

This is so weird because after this command I used another command to fetch sub-file of this DF and it returned success `61 12`.

```
command1(Select MPCOS Applet): 00 A4 04 00 10 A0 00 00 00 18 30 03 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
-> response: [97,18] (in decimal) or 6112 (in hex)

command2: 00 C0 00 00 12
-> response: [105,133,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] (in decimal) or
             69 85 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 (in hex)

command3(Select Root): 00 A4 00 00 02 3f 00
-> response: [97,18] (in decimal) or 6112 (in hex)

command4: 00 C0 00 00 12
-> response: [105,133,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] (in decimal) or
             69 85 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 (in hex)

command5(Select DF): 00 A4 01 00 02 02 00
-> response: [105,129] (in decimal) or 6981 (in hex)

command6(Select EF): 00 A4 02 00 02 02 01
-> response: [97,18] (in decimal) or 6112 (in hex)

command7: 00 C0 00 00 12
-> response: [105,133,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] (in decimal) or 
             69 85 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 (in hex)
```

Comment: Does using `00A4010002020000` (with _Le_ field) or `00A4010C020200` (with ISO7816-4 no response data) change anything?

Comment: Just an idea, does the sub-file access work _without_ this SELECT? Sort of file selection rules might apply...

Comment: Through the command of "00A40100020200" we receive error 6980, however we could access the sub-file (ES). Indeed we have found that if we omit this command we could not access to the sub-file. I mean that although we get error but this command work properly.
How we could escape from this error?

Comment: Which card are you using? Is it `T=0` or `T=1`? What are the responses to the proposed commands? What does card manual say about status `0x6980` (although reserved by ISO7816, not defined here).

Comment: @vlp please see the question again, there was a mistake that I correct that. Protocol T0 or T1 is for contact-less card.

Comment: @vlp the response is: Successfully  SC:6112:6112

Comment: What card is it? Javacard with an `MPCOS` applet?

Comment: yes my card is javacard with an MPCOS applet

Comment: I edited your question to be more readable for others. Please check it. If you can, please fill in the `...` parts in the responses. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @vlp for your edition, I filled the blanks and omitted the 9000 string from your edition, because 9000 is a response for a situation in which card is not waiting for the next command. Indeed when we selecting a part of data structure, card is waiting for next command to execute on the selected area.

Comment: Could you execute the following command sequence and update the question with the trace? `00 A4 04 00 10 A0 00 00 00 18 30 03 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00`, `00 C0 00 00 12`, `00 A4 00 00 02 3f 00`, `00 C0 00 00 12`, `00 A4 01 00 02 02 00`, `00 A4 02 00 02 02 01`, `00 C0 00 00 12`

Comment: @vlr
I tested your sequence and here is result:
command1-->6112, command2-->0000, command3-->6112, command4-->0000, command5-->6981, command6-->6112, command7-->0000

Comment: Are you sure about the `0000` status? Was it not `9000`? If so could you please include the data part of the responses to this `00 C0 00 00 12` commands? Have you ever heard about `GET RESPONSE` command?

Comment: @vlp yes you right, I have indicated only two last byte. Indeed the `Get Response` command cause to generate an array with 20 element:[105,133,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]. I think maybe my card does not support from this command.

Comment: This response is really strange. Is your reader software stack working properly? Do you have another card to test? I am afraid I am not able to help you (except upvoting the question which I already have done). Good luck! .. And let me(us) know about the outcome

Comment: @vlp I really appreciate you, I tested these sequence commands with several readers and several cards, but all of cards customized by Gemalto company for us. However I think maybe this problem is due to Fire Fox add-on. Because I am connecting the card through Fire Fox add-on. Although it use `winscard.dll`, FF use python core that it could be different from windows core.

Comment: Have you managed to resolve the problem? It might be worth trying another tool to send the same APDUs to the card and verify this quite odd responses.

Comment: Dear @vlp , I have tested this APDU by various card readers, I am confused how it is possible that there has not access to a file while there has an access to its sub-file.

Comment: None of your SELECT commands s is actually working, since each returns an error status. The trailing zero bytes are not compliant with ISO7816-4 in that case. 6981 most likely means, that an EF is found instead of a DF; try to use P1=0 instead. 6985 (conditions of use not satisfied) is more strange - check the MPCOS manual for possible reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the problem:

The problem was due to invoking the SCardTransmit function for two times. Indeed, one time to get response length and the second time for execute the command and getting response.

This dual invoke lead to error 6981:

```
function SCardTransmitFunc(aCallbackName, myCommand){
    var _SCARD_IO_REQUEST = new CONST.SCARD_IO_REQUEST;
    _SCARD_IO_REQUEST.dwProtocol = AProtocol;
    _SCARD_IO_REQUEST.cbPciLength =  CONST.SCARD_IO_REQUEST.size;  
    var myArrayCommand = hex2Dec(myCommand);        
    var command = TYPES.LPBYTE.targetType.array(myArrayCommand.length)(myArrayCommand);
    var commandLength = command.length;        
    var responseLength = TYPES.DWORD();
    var rez_SCT = SCardTransmit(cardHandle, _SCARD_IO_REQUEST.address(), command, commandLength, null, null, responseLength.address());
    var response = TYPES.LPBYTE.targetType.array(parseInt(responseLength.value))();
    var rez_SCT = SCardTransmit(cardHandle, _SCARD_IO_REQUEST.address(), command, commandLength, null, response, responseLength.address());
    var myResponse = "";//new Array();
    for(i = response.length - 2; i < response.length ; i++)
    {
        myResponse += dec2Hex(response[i]);
    }
}
```

and the corrected code is this:

```
function SCardTransmitFunc(aCallbackName, myCommand){
    var _SCARD_IO_REQUEST = new CONST.SCARD_IO_REQUEST;
    _SCARD_IO_REQUEST.dwProtocol = AProtocol;
    _SCARD_IO_REQUEST.cbPciLength =  CONST.SCARD_IO_REQUEST.size;  
    var myArrayCommand = hex2Dec(myCommand);
    var command = TYPES.LPBYTE.targetType.array(myArrayCommand.length)(myArrayCommand);
    var commandLength = command.length;
    var responseLength = TYPES.DWORD(1024);
    var response = TYPES.BYTE.array(parseInt(1024))();
    var rez_SCT = SCardTransmit(cardHandle, _SCARD_IO_REQUEST.address(), command, commandLength, null, response, responseLength.address());
    var myResponse = "";//new Array();
    var myLength = parseInt(responseLength.value);
    for(i = myLength - 2; i < myLength ; i++)
    {
        myResponse += dec2Hex(response[i]);
    }
}
```

I really thanks @guidot for his good hint and dear @vlp for his helps

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `00A4010002020000` command APDU (i.e. the same as before, but with a *Le* field) if you need to process the `SELECT` response (you can get it using the `GET RESPONSE` command as you probably already know).

Or you can use the `00A4010C020200` command APDU (i.e. the same as before, but with `P2=0x0C` to indicate no response data wanted) if you do not need to process the `SELECT` response.

Based on your comments this approach should work.

EDIT>

This is strange, I just reproduced your situation on a native MPCOS card (do not have access to the MPCOS applet right now):

```
00A40000023F00 -> 851080013F0038000000C100C100000000679000
00A40100020200 -> 6F15840E315041592E5359532E4444463031A5038801019000
00A40200020201 -> 85104302020105000040C000C0000000006B9000
```

Note: This trace does not show the `GET RESPONSE` APDU exchanges.

So probably I can't help you :(

Comment: Unfortunately did not work, I tried these two commands and it return 6981 error in both situation

Comment: What is your command for selecting Applet
(sth like my first command)?

Comment: As I use the native MPCOS card, I do not select the applet.